# whitespace above header won't leave. It's fine in safari but not firefox

Tags: css, firefox, whitespace, margin, padding

White space above header won't leave in firefox. It's fine in safari and IE. I've done no padding and no margin but it still won't work.
Everything was fine before I removed my left float from a bottom container.

```
body{margin:0 auto;
padding:0;}
a:link{text-decoration:none;}
#heading{
    margin:0px auto;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:lighter;
padding:0;

background-color:#ffffff ;
    }

#heading ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    float:right;
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;

}

#heading li{float:right;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
margin-left:20px;
margin-top:25px;
margin-right:12px;
padding:0;
}

#heading .ibar{float:left;
list-style-type:none;
margin-top:25px;
padding:0px;
}
```

**Html code**

```
    <div id = "heading">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Disqus
</li>
<li>Youtube
</li>
<li><a href="/rss">RSS
</li>
<li>Facebook
</li>
<li>Crunch
</li>
<li><a href="/ask">Disqus
</li>
<li><a href="/archive">Twitter
</li>
<li><a href="/">Home
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<li class = "avatar">
<img src="" width="300" height="200" >
</li>

<div class = "clear"></div>


</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `!important` for `padding` such as

```
     #heading
     {
      margin:0px auto;
      font-size:18px;
      font-weight:lighter;
      padding:0 !important;
      background-color:#ffffff ;
      }
```

Comment: can u please make jsfiddle of your code so we can solve your issue

Comment: i want it to be like from the jsfiddle site. The image is the problem i'm having. Theres white space above the heading and i want it gone. It works fine in everything except firefox.

Comment: try to use `!important` for header margin

Comment: or reset margin using `*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}`

Comment: alright. It's working. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it. Was scratching my head on this. lol :)

Answer (score 0):

close the "}" for #heading ID actually closed "}" is missed in #heading ID